# Spring Security Plugin Issue in Grails 2.4.4

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm following this tutorial for Spring Security Authentication:

http://spring.io/blog/2010/08/11/simplified-spring-security-with-grails/
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auwML_bsUEE

I can't follow the step in 4:50.

```
package org.example

import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

class PostController {
...
@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
def followAjax = { ... }

@Secured(['ROLE_USER', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])
def addPostAjax = { ... }

def global = { ... }

@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
def timeline = { ... }

@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'])
def personal = { ... }
}
```

import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured is not found.

I'm using Grails 2.4.4 and compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4' in BuildConfig.groovy. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured` from spring security directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is more than 4 years old, a lot has changed since then. Try reading the plugin docs - I'm sure that there are several other changes like this that will cause issues.

The import should be `grails.plugin.springsecurity.Secured`. You can also use the Spring Security `org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured` annotation, but the plugin's annotation supports all of the same features and a few additional ones, e.g. letting you define the rules with a Closure.

You can't use either annotation on an action defined as a Closure though. They are still supported in Grails 2.0+ but methods are now preferred, and although Grails lets you define actions with closures or actions, the plugin only supports methods.